# Connect Qprocess signal to slot

Tags: qt, signals, slot

In the function below, how do I connect the process signal errorOccured to a slot? My goal is to qDebug the errorOccurred property when process.startDetached() runs.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    qDebug() << "Start Detached";
    QProcess process;
   
    connect(process, SIGNAL(errorOccurred()), this, 
    SLOT(onSdetacherror()));

    process.setProgram("C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe");
    process.setArguments({"/k"});
    process.startDetached();


}
```

The proper connect syntax is eluding me ...

Comment: You cannot connect `startDetached()` to a slot because it is NOT a signal. If you are interested in writing the error which is passed from `errorOccurred()` signal, then of course connect to this signal. Though I am not sure if this will work for detached process. You need to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my question and added one of my attempts at the connect statement.

Comment: This is so called "old" style of connections. It is better to use the "new" style which provides more compile-time checks. See https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax which in your case should be `connect(&process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, &MainWindow::onSdetacherror);` But it will not work, because it will get disconnected once `QProcess` is destroyed, i.e. at the end of the scope. If you want to keep the connection alive, you need to create `QProcess` on the heap using `new`.

Comment: Btw. why do you need the process to be detached?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Using Qt 5.6 start won't open a console, startDetached will.